# How to make my JS solution functional?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, function, functional-programming

I've got some data that came from classy service in Angular that looks like this (briefly):

```
const obj = {
  field: [
    {
      id: 1,
      items: []
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      items: [ { wateva: 'wateva1' } ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      items: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      items: [ { yeah: 7 } ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

Well, my task is just to collect all array items, that are not empty.
My solution (actually my solution is written in TypeScript and Angular 5, but here to make it more simple and comprehensible it's going to be like...) :

```
function getItems() {
  const items = [];

  obj.field.forEach(currentField => {
    if (currentField.items && currentField.items.length) {
      currentField.items.forEach(currentItem => items.push(currentItem));
    }
  });

  return items;
}
```

Right, it's dead simple and it works as expected (current one will return...) :

```
[ { wateva: 'wateva1' }, { yeah: 7 } ]
```

And now my question... How to make my solution functional? I want to get rid of my new variable *items*, I don't want to push in that variable, I just want to return the result in one action. Any help will be appreciated.

*P.S.* Suggestions with 3rd libraries are not accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use es6 (and since you mentioned you're using typescript, that should be fine), you can turn this into a nice functional one-liner by combining `concat`, `map`, `filter`, and the spread operator:

```js
const obj = {
  field: [
    {
      id: 1,
      items: []
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      items: [ { wateva: 'wateva1' } ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      items: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      items: [ { yeah: 7 } ]
    }
  ] 
}

function getItems(obj) {
  return [].concat(...obj.field.map(o => o.items).filter(Array.isArray))
}

console.log(getItems(obj))
```

Comment: Well, obviously I can use es6 :) Thank u, man, that's great one and I'm pathetic :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flatMap` (stage 3)](http://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--Array-prototype--flatten--flatMap-). `flatMap` here matches Fantasy Land's spec for [`chain`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#monad).

```
data.field.flatMap
  (({ items }) =>
    Array.isArray (items) ? items : []
  )

// [ { wateva: 'wateva1' }, { yeah: 7 } ]
```

You can polyfill it in environments that don't have it

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f) {
  return this.reduce
    ( (acc, x) =>
        acc.concat (f (x))
    , []
    )
}
```

Full program demonstration

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f) {
  return this.reduce
    ( (acc, x) =>
        acc.concat (f (x))
    , []
    )
}

const data = 
  { field:
    [ { id: 1, items: [] }
    , { id: 2, items: [ { wateva: 'wateva1' } ] }
    , { id: 3, items: false }
    , { id: 4, items: [ { yeah: 7 } ] } 
    ]
  }

const result =
  data.field.flatMap
    (({ items }) =>
      Array.isArray (items) ? items : []
    )

console.log (result)
// [ { wateva: 'wateva1' }, { yeah: 7 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` and the spread operator to accumulate onto an empty array:

```
obj.field.reduce(
    (acc, current) => current.items && current.items.length > 0 ? [...acc, ...current.items] : acc, [])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [object destructuring, and spread assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
function getItems({ field }) {
    return field.reduce((result, { items }) => 
        items instanceof Array ? 
        items.reduce((items, item) => [...items, item], result) :
        result
    , []);
}
```